# How to output the hash table as Excel file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

Well My question is same as the question below. But this one has not been solved yet. I've tried the answer but it did not work. So is there any method to use the key as the headings and each group displayed on a new row?

[Export hashtable to CSV with the key as the column heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465430/powershell-hash-table-export-to-csv-with-the-key-as-the-column-heading)

Comment: Since your question is merely a reference to the other question I'm going to close it as a duplicate. I just posted an answer to the other question that should solve the problem. Feel free to comment there if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for your reply.