# Compare-Object - Separate side columns

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to display the results of a PowerShell `Compare-Object` in two columns showing the differences of reference vs difference objects?

For example using my current cmdline:

```
Compare-Object $Base $Test
```

Gives:

```
InputObject     SideIndicator
987654          =>
555555          <=
123456          <=
```

In reality the list is rather long. For easier data reading is it possible to format the data like so:

```
Base    Test
555555  987654
123456
```

So each column shows which elements exist in that object vs the other.

For bonus points it would be fantastic to have a count in the column header like so:

```
Base(2)  Test(1)
555555   987654
123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Sure. Feasible? Not so much. PowerShell wasn't really built for creating this kind of tabular output. What you can do is collect the differences in a hashtable as nested arrays by input file:

```
$ht = @{}
Compare-Object $Base $Test | ForEach-Object {
  $value = $_.InputObject
  switch ($_.SideIndicator) {
    '=>' { $ht['Test'] += @($value) }
    '<=' { $ht['Base'] += @($value) }
  }
}
```

then [transpose the hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808624/1630171):

```
$cnt  = $ht.Values |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Count } |
        Sort-Object |
        Select-Object -Last 1
$keys = $ht.Keys | Sort-Object

0..($cnt-1) | ForEach-Object {
  $props = [ordered]@{}
  foreach ($key in $keys) {
    $props[$key] = $ht[$key][$_]
  }
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

To include the item count in the header name change `$props[$key]` to `$props["$key($($ht[$key].Count))"]`.

Comment: This is awesome thanks. Powershell surprises me more every trick I learn!