# What's the difference between CSV and XLSX

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm trying to get some lists in an output with an Excel table but people tells "This is not the same using with CSV because each line is an individual object","Use lists to get the output you wish",and it complicate the situation because I don't know what to do right now. I'm using PowerShell. Can someone explain me the difference with XLSX  and CSV utilities with the import with an example If possible ? I watched some documentation but it didn't help me to understand.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.Column1)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}

$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 | where Column1 -ne ''
$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 | where Column2 -ne ''
```

the output expected

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
-------   -------   -------   -------
infra-98 infra-852 infra-44  infra-99
infra-62 infra-85  infra-8   infra-23
         infra-8   infra-852 infra-10
         infra-55            infra-70


Column1   Column2    Column3    Column4
-------   -------    -------    -------
infra-1   infra-85   infra-2     infra-99
infra-98  infra-55   infra-44    infra-23
infra-2              infra-1     infra-10
infra-62                         infra-70
```

Comment: Your question doesn't go into much detail or contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Comment: From what I understand, I can give you this advice: Try to forget what you know until know, and look up what object orientation means, how that works in powershell, what the CSV format is (no hirachies). XLSX (Excel-Files) is not a Powershell format at all. It is comparable to CSV files like birds are to bricks. You seem to have some basic misunderstanding, from my point of view.

Comment: xlsx is a binary data format used by Microsoft Excel (actually it's zip folders with XML files in them). CSV is a tabular plaintext format. Looks to me like what you actually want to do is collect your columns in distinct arrays, and then [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808624/1630171) those.

Comment: If I would transpose it like link up there, I should add some code every hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is lost from the your previous questions, when you import a .CSV using the `Import-CSV` cmdlet. Then each line of the CSV becomes a PowerShell object. The same would be true if you imported an XLSX using the [`ImportExcel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/3.0.0) module. The structure is no longer the same as a CSV file or a XLSX file. It's no longer a spreadsheet, but a collection of objects.

Take the simple .CSV file

```
Col1,Col2
a,b
c,a
```

If you were to import this using `Import-CSV` PowerShell, then you would get an array of two objects. Which could be better pictured like this:

```
@(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Col1 = 'a'
        Col2 = 'b'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Col1 = 'c'
        Col2 = 'a' 
    }
)
```

So it is a two separate objects, with properties from the column headers.

If you set a property in one of these objects to an empty string, then when you export and turn the objects back into rows. You will have an empty "cell".

How to get around this is to read your columns in as individual arrays, then perform the comparison logic on those arrays, then create a totally new collection of object from those updated arrays, then export. Which other people have answered in your other questions.