# Transpose or output data to row based table

Tags: database, powershell, datatable, transpose

I am having trouble figuring out how to output a row based data table in PowerShell. I am able to do it standard Columnar based data table, but not the other way around.

My current output looks like:

```
            Books  Cables  Pens 
   Client1      1       0     0
   Client2      2       4     6
   Client3      1       3    10
```

The Books, Cables and Pens are constant, and I have new Clients to add.

I need to be able to output a table where I can narrow it down by filtering for both the client and item

I Need to have it look like this:

```
          Client1   Client2   Client3
 Books          1         2         1
 Cables         0         4         3
 Pens           0         6        10
```

I currently Use key/value pair to fill in data from a separate object:

```
$ctable = foreach ($client in $clientstuff) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        Client = $client.name
        Books  = $client.books.Count
       Cables = $client.cables.Count
       Pens   = $client.pens.Count
    }
 }

 $ctable= $ctable | Format-table
```

Need to format as table otherwise it comes out as list
I have 100s of clients and more than 40 different items, so I cant exactly hard code each.

I figured I could maybe use System.Data.Datatable but if so I am not sure how.

I have looked at the solution provided in 
 [Export hashtable to CSV with the key as the column heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465430/export-hashtable-to-csv-with-the-key-as-the-column-heading)

But I cant seem to make it work, Even the answers were not marked as answering the question in the question. No matter how I adapt it, it will only get me errors. ALSO the solution does not meet my requirement of being filterable by both item and client, it just turns it into a numbered list with multiple columns.

I have also looked at a number of other links, but again those have always been more like lists rather than parseable tables which can be filtered by BOTH the RowName (item) and ColumnName (client)

Preferably I would like a method to output generically into row based table, but if not transposing is fine too

Comment: use this -[TRANSPOSE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-to-7c8368be)

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried using it and replacing the servers stuff etc, but that didnt quite work out

Comment: Let me look into it then. I will try

Comment: Thanks, while it does transpose it order wise, you cant parse it by item.... because it just prints the client name and numbers with no reference to the item

Comment: What does "*but again those have always been more like lists rather than parseable tables*" mean? PowerShell "Tables" are list of objects, rendered as a table, the rows are individual objects, and the 'columns' are their property names, in what way can they be 'parseable'? "*I cant seem to make it work [..]  it will only get me errors.*" - what errors? "*tables which can be filtered*" - filtered how?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am basically trying to replicate the normal parseability functionality that you can do in key-value pair `pscustomobject` except in row format rather than columnar format... normally you can just go  `$ctable.where({$_client -eq "client1"}).Pens` and get a value based on both the item and the client. But the output of the PSCUSTOMOBJECT is columnar, I am trying to make it row based

Comment: @RanadipDutta Sorry, I am not sure I understand