# How can I export multiple objects to different CSV columns in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I scraped one website and what I really want is to have a CSV file that contains the scraped strings each in a separate column.

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "SomeURL"

$obj  = $page.ParsedHtml.Body.GetElementsByTagName('SomeTag') |
        Where {$_.GetAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'someValue'}
$obj1 = $page.ParsedHtml.Body.GetElementsByTagName('SomeAnotherTag') |
        Where {$_.GetAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'someAnotherValue'}
$obj2 = $page.ParsedHtml.Body.GetElementsByTagName('yetAnotherTag') |
        Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'yetAnotherValue'}

$locations  = $obj.InnerText   
$locations1 = $obj1.InnerText
$locations2 = $obj2.InnerText

$toExport0 = $locations | Select-Object @{Name='locations';Expression={$_}}
$toExport1 = $locations1 | Select-Object @{Name='AnotherSetOflocations';Expression={$_}}
$toExport2 = $locations2 | Select-Object @{Name='YetAnotherSetOflocations';Expression={$_}}
```

Each of `$locations`, `$locaitons1`, and `$locations2` contains scraped strings. When I output them it's like this:

```
word
another word
yet another word
.
.
.
```

The output that I want is (exporting it to CSV file separated in columns):

```
locations,anotherSetOfLocations,YetAnotherSetOfLocations
word,...,...
another word,...,...
yet another word,...,...
.
.
.
```

Comment: How is the first column going to contain `toExport0` when that already contains a column and a value? How are `toExport1` and `toExport2` defined? What kind of output do you need to see? `export-csv -append` will append, but that doesn't fit with what you describe.

Comment: I export `$toExport0` like this `$toExport0 | Export-Csv foo.csv -NoType` since `name='locations'` this makes a column in csv file with "location" word as a header and then all the strings that is in `$locations`
`toExport1` and `toExport2` are defined the same way as `toExport0` (i.e. `$toExport1 = $locations1 | select-object @{name='anotherSetOfLoc`;Expression={$_}}
I tried `-append` before. It is not working for me, here is the error (The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: locations)

Comment: The output I want to have is an Excel sheet where `$toExport0` is in A column and `$toExport1` in B column and so on..

Comment: "*toExport1 and toExport2 are defined the same way*", you say, showing them defined differently.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say both of them defined using the notation `$someObj | select-object @{name='something';Expression{$_}}`

Comment: PowerShell normally works in rows, not columns. Possible duplicate of [Export hashtable to CSV with the key as the column heading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31465430/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

In these bits:

```
$toExport0 = $locations | select-object @{Name='locations'; Expression={$_}}
```

You are creating three separate objects, and that won't work for the CSV creation. Remove those lines, and do it all at once after you have the locations.

You need one object, with three properties on it:

```
$toExport = [PSCustomObject]@{

    'locations'       = $locations
    'anotherSetOfLoc' = $locations2
    'locations3'      = $locations3

}

$toExport | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I tried such thing. This is exporting `System.Object[]` instead of the actual content of `$locations`

Comment: @WorthyNull `$locations -join ' '`

Comment: @ansgarWiechers This is exporting the first element of `$locations`, not the whole thing.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a loop in your code, and you are doing your `select` inside the loop and you've replaced it with my PSCustomobject selection outside the loop instead? I dunno, details matter and two of us have tried to guess the details and got it wrong, I can only second AnsgarWiechers request to "Please update your question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code as well as sample input data and an example of the actual and the desired output".

Comment: Again, Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question. now it includes the whole code.

Comment: Okay. I updated it once more. I believe now It includes everything you have asked for. Thanks in advance!