# Multiple rows in a grid

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to list all ad group memberships of specific users. The input would be a string of logins split with a comma `'login1,login2'`.
So I go over each user and list their memberships with the username as title. Somehow it only shows the first entry. Also it shows the user groups in one row and I don't know how to change that.

Code below:

```
$users = $logon -split ','
$q = @()

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $usernm = Get-ADUser -Filter 'samAccountName -like $user' | select Name
    $useraccess = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Select-Object Name
    $userobj = New-Object PSObject
    $userobj | Add-Member Noteproperty $usernm.Name $useraccess.Name
    $q += $userobj
}
```

Expected output would be something like:

```
fullnameuser1           fullnameuser2         list of users goes on...
-------------           -------------         ------------------------
adgroup1                adgroup3              ...
adgroup2                adgroup4
...                     ...
```

In principle this would also mean that if i typed `$q.'fullnameuser1'` output would be:

```
fullnameuser1 
-------------
adgroup1
adgroup2
...
```

Whenever the code is ran, it will only ever add the first user's access, also returning all groups on one row. So somehow I need to go over all the group memberships and add a row for each one.

Comment: please specify what you expect/what the the output should look like. if you specify `$users = 'login1','login2'` you don't have to split them, as it would be an array which you could iterate through.

Comment: It's fine how the input is handles because that is what is taken from a file so it has to split it first. I expect it to return the groups with the usernames as headers, just like is written.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, PowerShell does not expand variables in single-quoted strings. Because of that `Get-ADUser` will never find a match unless you have a user with the literal account name `$user`. Also, using the `-like` operator without wildcards produces the same results as the `-eq` operator. If you're looking for an exact match use the latter. You probably also need to add nested quotes.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -eq '${user}'"
```

---

**Correction:** `Get-ADUser` seems to resolve variables in filter strings by itself. I verified and the statement

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'samAccountName -eq $user'
```

does indeed return the user object for `$user` despite the string being in single quotes.

---

If you want a fuzzy match it's better to use [ambiguous name resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx).

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=${user})"
```

You may also want to avoid appending to an array in a loop, and adding members to custom objects after creation. Both are slow operations. Collect the loop output in a variable, and specify the object properties directly upon object creation.

```
$q = foreach ($user in $users) {
    ...
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property {
        $usernm.Name = $useraccess.Name
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'd consider using the user's name as the property name bad design. That would be okay if you were building a hashtable (which is mapping unique keys to values), but for custom objects the property names should be identical for all objects of the same variety.

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property {
    Name  = $usernm.Name
    Group = $useraccess.Name
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you missed my point. First of all, the user lookup part works fine, it might not be the optimal solution, but I'm trying to get this to work, period. All I need help with is which kind of operation I need to perform to get the output in multiple columns when there are multiple users.

Comment: `PS> $user = 'erth'`

`PS> $usernm = Get-ADUser -Filter 'samAccountName -like $user' | select Name`

`PS> $usernm` gives output: 
`Name: Ernst Thom` This output seems to work for me, so I just want to have a look at my actual issue because the output I want is the output I get. All I need is for the output to be placed in multiple columns.

Comment: As for `Get-ADUser`, you're right about that. I just verified, and it actually does resolve the variable despite it being in a single-quoted string. This must be something the cmdlet does, though, because it isn't normal PowerShell behavior. Updated my answer.

Comment: It is probably because of the ldap roots or something, but I edited the question with expected output now.

Comment: Ah, now I see. The output format you're asking for isn't really how PowerShell handles data. In tabular format object data is displayed in a row, not a column. You can [transpose your data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465972/1630171) to get the output you want, but it's rather awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Basily query all the users and store it in `$users`, example:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=domain,dc=local"
```

And then you can export the results as csv or a table.

To Export as CSV :

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership <Username> | select name, groupcategory, groupscope | export-CSV C:\data\ADUserGroups.csv`
```

To Format the result as Table in the console itslef :

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership <Username> | select name, groupcategory, groupscope | Format-Table
```

Comment: I am trying to get the results in a specific format. I know the queries you suggest here, thanks anyways.