# How to group and sum integer values

Tags: powershell

I have a variable with the following content:

```
VMName  Drive Size
------- ----- ----
Server1 D:     100
Server1 E:     150
Server1 E:     100
Server2 E:     200
Server2 E:     250
```

Now I'd like to group the VMNames according to the name and the drive and then sum up the sizes, so that it returns the following:

```
VMName  Drive Size
------- ----- ----
Server1 D:    100
Server1 E:    250
Server2 E:    450
```

Alternatively (and even better) in the following format:

```
VMName  D     E
------- ----- ----
Server1 100   250
Server2 0     450
```

This is the current script I am using:

```
$VMs = Get-VM -ComputerName "FOOBAR"
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
  $HardDrives = $VM.HardDrives
  foreach ($HardDrive in $HardDrives) {
    $objVM = New-Object System.Object
    $objVM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VMName -Value $VM.VMName
    $objVM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Drive -Value $HardDrive.path.Substring(0,2).ToUpper()

    $HDs = (Get-VHD -ComputerName "FOOBAR" -Path $HardDrive.path)
    $objVM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Size -Value ($HDs.Size/1GB)

    $objVM |
    Group-Object VMName, Drive |
    Select-Object @{n='VMName----------------';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand VMName -First 1}} ,
              @{n='Drive';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand Drive -First 1}},
              @{n='Size';e={($_.Group | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum}}
  }
}
```

Current Output:

```
VMName---------------- Drive Size
---------------------- ----- ----
TEST01                 E:     127
TEST02                 E:     127
TEST03                 E:      40
TEST03                 E:     100
TEST03                 E:     100
```

Desired Output:

```
VMName---------------- Drive Size
---------------------- ----- ----
TEST01                 E:     127
TEST02                 E:     127
TEST03                 E:     240
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0) for grouping the items and [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-3.0) for calculating the sums.

```
$VM.HardDrives |
    Select-Object VMName, @{n='Drive';e={$_.path.Substring(0,2).ToUpper()}},
                  @{n='Size';e={(Get-Vhd -Computer "FOOBAR" -Path $_.path).Size/1GB}} |
    Group-Object VMName, Drive |
    Select-Object @{n='VMName';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand VMName -First 1}},
                  @{n='Drive';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand Drive -First 1}},
                  @{n='Size';e={($_.Group | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum}}
```

If you don't want to work with calculated properties you could build new custom objects in a `ForEach-Object` loop instead:

```
$VM.HardDrives | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'VMName' = $_.VMName
        'Drive'  = $_.path.Substring(0,2).ToUpper()
        'Size'   = (Get-Vhd -Computer "FOOBAR" -Path $_.path).Size/1GB
    }
} | Group-Object VMName, Drive | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'VMName' = $_.Group | Select -Expand VMName -First 1
        'Drive'  = $_.Group | Select -Expand Drive -First 1
        'Size'   = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

As for the alternative output format you mentioned in your question: that doesn't play well with how PowerShell organizes data. You could get that format by [transposing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808624/1630171) the data from above, but it's really awkward.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it still doesn't work correctly. The output is still not grouped together .. I've tried with both methods (see updated code above)

Comment: Thanks again Ansgar. Do I maybe need to convert the "size" column in order to sum them together?

Comment: You're grouping each individual object *by itself*. Of course that's not going to work. Replace your entire `foreach` loop with the code I posted.