# How to format a hash table with an array?

Tags: powershell, formatting, hashtable

I want to display a hashtable in PowerShell and I want to use an array to fill one of the columns.

Basically, what I have is this:

```
$Servers = "training01.us", "training02.us", "training03.us"

#Table
$table = @(@{ColumnA="$Servers";ColumnB=online})
$table.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

What I would want it to do is display each server on a different row in the table. For example:

```
ColumnA
-------
training01.us
training02.us
training03.us
```

But instead I get this displayed:

```
ColumnA
-------
training01.us training02.us training03.us
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: from what i can tell you will either need to write your own format code OR make a hashtable with one value per key instead of an array in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the desired output:

```
$Servers = "training01.us", "training02.us", "training03.us"
$OFS = "`n"
$table = @(@{ColumnA="$Servers";ColumnB='online'})
$table.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Beware, though, that all servers are still in the same field (as a single string). The three name strings are merely joined with newlines (by setting the Output Field Separator to `` `n ``).

`Format-Table -Wrap` then displays the wrapped string value without truncating the output.

Another way to the same result (without having to modify `$OFS`) would be

```
$table = @(@{ColumnA=$Servers -join "`n";ColumnB='online'})
$table.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Comment: Both of them worked fine. Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to make them separate strings? I don't need the code for that, just curious.

Comment: Possible: yes. However, PowerShell doesn't normally organize data in columns. Attempts to do so tend to be [awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808624/1630171).

Comment: would this change if ColumnB had a variable inside it that is an array like $Servers?

Comment: Maybe, mabe not. It depends on what data you have.